# Create a product in a category hibernate - Transcient issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I use two class as models to build a JSON :

The productCreateRequestModel:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ProductCreateRequestModel {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int qty;
    private String imgPath;

    private CategoryRequestCreateProductModel category;
}
```

My CategoryRequestCreateProductModel

```
@Getter @Setter
public class CategoryRequestCreateProductModel {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String categoryKeyId;
}
```

I created 2 entities to manage categories and products.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
@Getter @Setter
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String productKeyId;

    // many to one relationship with category
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryEntity category;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int qty;

    private String imgPath;
}
```

And :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
@Getter @Setter
public class CategoryEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String categoryKeyId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable=true)
    private CategoryEntity parentCategory;

    // allow to delete also subcategories
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CategoryEntity> subCategories;

    //Here mappedBy indicates that the owner is in the other side
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<ProductEntity> products;
}
```

This generated this table in the database.

[image]

In my controller:

```
public ProductRestResponseModel createProduct(@RequestBody ProductCreateRequestModel productCreateRequestModel) throws Exception {
    ProductRestResponseModel returnValue = new ProductRestResponseModel();

    if(productCreateRequestModel.getName().isEmpty() || productCreateRequestModel.getPrice() <= 0)
        throw new ApplicationServiceException(ErrorMessages.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS.getErrorMessage());

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    ProductDto productDto = modelMapper.map(productCreateRequestModel, ProductDto.class);

    ProductDto createdProduct = productService.createProduct(productDto);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdProduct, ProductRestResponseModel.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

In my Service I use the DTO:

```
@Override
public ProductDto createProduct(ProductDto productDto) {
    ProductDto returnValue = new ProductDto();

    if (productRepository.findByName(productDto.getName()) != null)
        throw new ApplicationServiceException("Record already in Database");

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    ProductEntity productEntity = modelMapper.map(productDto, ProductEntity.class);

    String productKeyId = utils.generateProductKeyId(30);
    productEntity.setProductKeyId(productKeyId);

    ProductEntity storedProduct = productRepository.save(productEntity);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(storedProduct, ProductDto.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

My issue is when I send a post request with this object :

```
{
    "name": "Pizza",
    "price": 344.0,
    "qty": 15,
    "imgPath": "new/pathImage",
    "category": {
        "categoryKeyId": "23ume70Fu6yqyGUWfQkW110P4ko3gZ",
        "name": "CatName"
    }
}
```

When i send this request I obtain an error message : org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.app.ws.io.entity.ProductEntity.category -> com.app.ws.io.entity.CategoryEntity

My problem is that the Category already exists in the database and that i just need to set the foreign key in the product table